# Can I keep an ASP.NET Core web site running after stopping debugging?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, and am missing one feature I use a lot.

When setting up a new ASP.NET MVC project (pre Core), I would open the project properties, and from the Web tab, uncheck the Edit And Continue checkbox. That way, I could run my project, browse it in the browser, stop debugging in VS, and it would continue to run.

This meant I could make changes, recompile and reload the page, without having to start debugging again. Unless I actually needed to break in the code, this was much faster than starting a new debugging session after every change.

Can this be done in ASP.NET Core? I haven't managed to find a way yet.

Comment: start without debugging(ctrl +F5) instead of with debugging.

Comment: @JohanHerstad Interesting, based on my experiences with previous versions of ASP.NET, I initially dismissed your comment as wrong, but having spotted this point in a book last night, I just tried it, and it works beautifully! Please can you add it as an answer, and explain why it's different from previous versions, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit the properties for the web site project (right-click in Solution Explorer and select *Properties*) and then select the *Debug* tab on the right.

Under *Web Server Settings*, change *Hosting Model* to **Out of Process**.

[image]

Now, when debugging is stopped the website should continue to run in IIS Express.

*Notes:*

- Tested in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019
- The default hosting model for VS2017 is "In Process", in case you're wondering.
- It does not appear to make a difference whether or not you have 'Enable Edit and Continue' selected in Tools > Options > Debugging.

Comment: That's completely brilliant! So much easier than the other suggestions. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can start Kestel from the command line and add the watch command. In your project folder run the command:

```
dotnet watch run
```

Anytime you save a file in Visual Studio the watch will automatically restart the web server and your pages will show the changes you made.

You can also add a profile to you `launchSettings.json` and start the profile with Ctrl-F5, or Debug > Start Without Debugging.

```
"Dotnet Watch": {
  "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
  "launchUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Lastly, for me anyways, you can add it to your Visual Studio tools. Then you have it available in any projects you are working on.

"Tools > External Tools..."

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I sort of got it working, but had to play with the port numbers. It's all a bit painful though, why can't we do it like we used to?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to edit your app while it runs you have to run it without debugging (ctrl +F5). The point of this is so you can use .net core services like browser link(enabled in development mode), which actually let's you open your app in many browsers at the same time. Your app will run unless you specifically shut it down, for example by closing it through iis express. It uses signal r to keep a connection, but if you make certain changes, for example to the database code, you will have to start it again to see the changes. It is very lightweight, so you don't have to close the app through iis, just retype ctrl and f5 and it will start again.

Remember, your asp.net core app comes with it's own webserver, kestrel. So you can also run it without iis.

In debug mode, the purpose is to analyze your app, for example by setting breakpoints where executions stops so you can look through the stack. This is different than without debugging, because the purpose isn't to change the app on the fly as that would make no sense. You are testing your current version, changing it in debugging mode would potentially obscure other flaws etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, great explanation!